# in an array, Count the Positives and give the Sum of Negatives in Ruby

Tags: ruby, count, sum

The question says:

Given an array of integers.

Return an array, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers. 0 is neither positive nor negative.

If the input is an empty array or is null, return an empty array.

```
  def count_positives_sum_negatives(last)
     pos = []
     neg = []

     x = lst.each

      if x % 2 == 0
       pos.push x
       else neg.push x
      end
     y = pos.count
     z = neg.sum

   puts "[#{y},#{z}]"
  end
```

I tested with

```
 count_positives_sum_negatives([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15])
 #should return [10, -65]
```

I am unsure why my one only gives an error message:

```
An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: if (x % 2) == 0

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `%' for #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]:each>
# ./lib/solution.rb:7:in `count_positives_sum_negatives'
# ./lib/solution.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
No examples found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also certainly meant `lst.each do |x|` rather than `x = lst.each`. You get the error you do because `lst.each` without a block returns an `Enumerator` object, and that does not respond to `%`.

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  pos = []
  neg = []

  lst.each do |x|
    if x % 2 == 0
      pos.push x
    else 
      neg.push x
    end
  end
  
  y = pos.count
  z = neg.sum

  puts "[#{y},#{z}]"
end
```

Note: `x % 2 == 0` can be written as `x.even?`

But you're looking at evens and odds, and your description says count *positives* and sum *negatives*. You can use `#positive?` and `#negative?` for this, along with `#partition`.

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  pos, neg = lst.partition(&:positive?)

  y = pos.count
  z = neg.sum

  puts "[#{y},#{z}]"
end
```

You could also use `#each_with_object` to give you the info you're looking for.

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  lst.each_with_object([0, 0]) do |x, arr|
    if x.positive?
      arr[0] += 1
    else 
      arr[1] += x
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

@Chris has given the reason for your problem.

I think I would be inclined to write it as follows.

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  non_pos = lst.reject(&:positive?)
  [lst.size - non_pos.size, non_pos.sum]
end
```

```
count_positives_sum_negatives [-1, 2, 0, 0, 1, -4, -7, 0, 6]
  #=> [3, -12]
```

This has the weakness that a temporary array is created (`non_pos`), but `lst.size - non_pos.size` and `non_pos.sum` are both relatively fast calculations, the latter because it is implemented in C. One would have to benchmark, however.

`lst.reject(&:positive?)` is a short form of `lst.reject { |n| n.positive? )`.

See [Array#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) and [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Comment: There's also `lst.reject(&:zero?).partition(&:positive?).then { |pos, neg| [pos.count, neg.sum] }`.

Comment: @muistooshort you don't even need to reject zeros as they end up in `neg` and won't affect its sum.

Comment: How would you make it reject nil values?

Comment: @Stefan True but sometimes I like to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this final one I've done outputs the correct answer, but I think the portal itself is broken as it cannot tell that [10, -65] is the same as [10, -65]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jzUo.png)

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  pos = []
  neg = []

  lst.each do |x|
    if x.positive?
      pos.push x
    else 
      neg.push x
    end
  end
  
  y = pos.count
  z = neg.sum
  
  final = []
 final << y
 final << z
  
  print final
end
```

Comment: You _print_ count and sum, but your method is supposed to _return_ these as a two-element array.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed that. But now I'm facing an issue of when the array inputted contains a nil value. My code returns it as [0, 0] instead of [].

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

I've currently tried this:

```def count_positives_sum_negatives(last)

  pos = []
  neg = []

  lst.each do |x|
    if x.positive?
      pos.push x
    else 
      neg.push x
    end
  end
  
  y = pos.count
  z = neg.sum

  if y.nil? || z.nil?
  return []
    else return [y, z]
  end
end```

Comment: You might as well just `puts [pos.count, neg.sum]`. Not a lot of sense to giving such short-lived names to things.